# Needing help updating a TimeSpan value using form field in Visual Studio

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio-2022, timespan

I have a Visual Studio project using supportedRuntime version="v4.0" and .NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2 with Microsoft Forms.  I am using a default json settings file to load the initial settings when the application starts.  I am able to add TexTBox and NumericUpDown fields to my form to read and update values from the json file.

However, I have not found a way to update a TimeSpan value. I have tried using a TextBox and NumericUpDown and this will read the TimeSpan value and display the time in the form field. However, I am unable to update the TimeSpan value using the form field.  I have also tried using DateTimePicker field (Formatted for just 24 hour time) in my form and this too will display the TimeSpan value but once again I am unable to edit the value using the datetime form field. For example, after changing the time from 03:00:00 to 04:00:00 the value will revert back to the default value as soon as you exit the field.  I had this same behavior using both the TextBox and The DateTimePicker.

I have included the different code snippets for may application relating to the TimeSpan value.  This value is setting the time to run a SQL backup.

```cs
this.TxtPickBackupStartTime.DataBindings.Add(
    nameof(this.TxtPickBackupStartTime.Text), applicationSettings,
    nameof(applicationSettings.StartBackupAt), false,
    DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation)

this.TxtPickBackupStartTime = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();

this.Controls.Add(this.TxtPickBackupStartTime);

private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox TxtPickBackupStartTime;

public TimeSpan StartBackupAt;

StartBackupAt = new TimeSpan(3, 0, 0),

settings.json file:
"StartBackupAt": "03:00:00",
```

[image]

I am currently getting the following error after implementing Oliver's suggestion below when replacing timeModelBindingSource with applicationSettings.StartBackupAt.

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Joey

Below are the two parts are the code that I hope would provide additional information.

```
namespace TendBackupApplication.Forms
{
    public partial class SettingsDialog : Form
    {
        private readonly ApplicationSettings applicationSettings;

        public SettingsDialog(ApplicationSettings applicationSettings)
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.applicationSettings = applicationSettings;

            this.txtTime.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", this.applicationSettings.StartBackupAt, "Time", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation, "T"));
```

.

```
namespace TendBackupLibrary.Settings
{
    public delegate void ApplicationSettingsSavedEvent(object sender, EventArgs e);

    public class ApplicationSettings
    {
        private readonly SettingsReader settingsReader;
        private readonly SettingsFile defaultSettings;
        private SettingsFile previousSettings;
        private SettingsFile currentSettings;

        public ApplicationSettings(SettingsReader settingsReader)
        {
            this.settingsReader = settingsReader;
            this.defaultSettings = new SettingsFile
            {
                DatabaseName = "Tend",   
                StartBackupAt = new TimeSpan(03, 00, 00),
                BackupInterval = 10
                MaxDatabaseCopies = 1,
                MonitorInterval = 3, // seconds
                MaxMonitorFailures = 3,
                Enabled = true,
```

Here is the TimeSpan Function

```
public TimeSpan StartBackupAt
{
    get
    {
        return this.currentSettings.StartBackupAt;
    }
    set
    {
        this.currentSettings.StartBackupAt = value;
    }
}
```

settings.json file

```
"DatabaseName": "Tend",
  "StartBackupAt": "03:00:00",
  "BackupInterval": 10,
  "OverwriteDatabase": true,
  "MaxDatabaseCopies": 1,
  "MonitorInterval": 3,
  "MaxMonitorFailures": 3,
  "Enabled": true,
```

Answer (score 0):

It works by binding the `TextBox.Text` property to a `DateTime` property of a model class. Just make sure to specify the `T` date/time format to suppress the display of the date part.

Example:

```cs
public class TimeModel
{
    public DateTime Time
    {
        get { return new DateTime(TimeSpan.Ticks); }
        set { TimeSpan = value.TimeOfDay; }
    }

    public TimeSpan TimeSpan { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
this.txtTime.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Text",
     this.timeModelBindingSource, "Time", true,
     System.Windows.Forms.DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation, null, "T"));
```

---

**Update**

Now that I see the relevant parts of your code, I can more precise answer.

Add this property to your class

```cs
public DateTime StartBackupAtDateTime
{
    get { return new DateTime(StartBackupAt.Ticks); }
    set { StartBackupAt = value.TimeOfDay; }
}
```

Compile you app to make this new property visible to the binding mechanism.

Add a `BindingSource` component and a Data Source based on your `ApplicationSettings` class as described in [WinForms – Bind controls to an object data source](https://makolyte.com/how-to-bind-controls-to-an-object-data-source-in-a-winforms-app-net-core-project/).

Delete any bindings from your textbox. Add a new binding to your TextBox as explained in the link. I.e., select your TextBox and in the properties window select `(DataBindings)` / `(Advanced)` and select your BindingSource component and `StartBackupAtDateTime` (instead of `Name` as the image in the link says) from the Binding drop-down. This does the `DataBindings.Add` thing automatically in the form.designer.cs file automatically.

All what remains to do is to assign the settings to the BindingSource:

```
// Replace bindingSource1 by the real name of your BindingSource.
bindingSource1.DataSource = applicationSettings;
```

Note that you must assign the whole settings object, not `applicationSettings.StartBackupAtDateTime`.

That's it.

Comment: Oliver, I appreciate your help.  I am a bit lost on how to implement your code.  I understand that I need to replace "this.TxtPickBackupTime..." with  "this.txtTime....." but I am not sure where to implement TimeModel public class.  I am also getting an error for the .Add "that the object does not contain a definition for "Add"".  I tried updating ... this.Controls.Add(this.txtTime); but I also get an error "cannot convert object to system.windows.forms.control  If you can provide an example using the code I provided that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `txtTime` is a `TextBox` and works like `this.TxtPickBackupStartTime.DataBindings.Add(...`. So there must be a `Add` method there. I just created this class to test the binding with a TextBox (you can create it anywhere) and assigned it like this: `timeModelBindingSource.DataSource = new TimeModel();`. Of course you must add an object BindingSource based on this class.

Comment: I am a bit confused about your JSON settings file. Isn't that a .NET Core thing? The standard WinForms settings file in the old Framework is XML and is read-only.

Comment: Oliver, thank you for clarifying.  I resolved the error about Add method due to a type-o.  Please confirm that timeModelBindingSource needs to be replaced with StartBackupAt.  This is the value I need to get and set in the json file.  I do not see from your example were you are referencing this value.

Comment: As far as the json file goes, I have other values that are Text, NumericUpDown and check box values that I am able to get and set using my form.  I can also manual edit the settings.json file and the form fields will update.  I am trying to expose the StartBackupAt value in the form so I do not have to manually edit the settings.json for this to be reflected in the application.

Comment: I have added the form to my original post.  All field except the Backup Start time I am able to get and set using this form.  There is a Windows service that I create that uses these parameters.  Any changes do not take effect until the service is restarted.  The settings.json file is update on validation of the change and is also saved to the form when Save is pressed.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know what the type of `applicationSettings` is. I tried with my XML app settings which creates a `internal sealed partial class Settings : global::System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase`, but the settings are read-only properties that do not allow editing. `timeModelBindingSource` is a `System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource` component I put on the form with my class as an object data source. See: [Bind controls to an object data source](https://makolyte.com/how-to-bind-controls-to-an-object-data-source-in-a-winforms-app-net-core-project/).

Comment: I have provided additional code in my original post that I hope will provide enough information to assist with exposing the StartBackupAt value in my form so I can bind to it and get and set a value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254864/discussion-between-joey-coyle-and-olivier-jacot-descombes).